# Centering <img> tags in a <div> tag via html in WordPress

Tags: html

What am I doing wrong here?

I am brand new to the web development world.

I want to center these two images, and am having no such luck:

```
<!-- WHITE SPACE LOGO AREA -->
<div style="background-color:white;color:white;padding:20px;">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/affiliate-color-logo.jpg" alt="American Welding Society Member" class="midImg">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/ASNT-corp_mem_logo_webrgb.jpg" alt="ASNT Corporate Partner" class="midImg">
</div>
```

Comment: Add `text-align: center;` to your div's `style` attribute: `<div style="background-color:white;color:white;padding:20px;text-align: center;">`

Comment: What CSS have you tried? I see nothing in your code that hints that it should be centered.

Comment: well embarrassingly enough, I am so new to this, I don't have any understanding how the html and css even relate to each other. I thought I could accomplish the centering thru html alone. This is not the case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text-align: center`, see this example:

```html
<div style="background-color:white;color:white;padding:20px;text-align: center;">
  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/affiliate-color-logo.jpg" alt="American Welding Society Member" class="midImg">
  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/ASNT-corp_mem_logo_webrgb.jpg" alt="ASNT Corporate Partner" class="midImg">
</div>
```

But it is a better practice not to use inline styling, see the following improved code using classes and CSS:

```css
.images {
  background-color:white;
  color:white;
  padding:20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/affiliate-color-logo.jpg" alt="American Welding Society Member" class="midImg">
  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/ASNT-corp_mem_logo_webrgb.jpg" alt="ASNT Corporate Partner" class="midImg">
</div>
```

Comment: @Niki You're welcome, kindly mark this as the correct answer for future references.